# git and docker together

Tags: git, docker

I am practicing git and docker and I want to use an application that uses both tools, for example, do some containerized app but track code changes, make branches and so on using git, I wonder what is the best way to do that.

- what should I do first, a docker image or a git repository?
- what should I put in .dockerignore and .gitignore? for example, should I include in gitignore the docker image or dockerfile?

I would like to know your workflow. any other recommendations would be helpful, thanks you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a git repository first.  This will put your `Dockerfile` under version control.  You should not put your `.gitignore` in your `Dockerfile`, but it is generally good practice to put `.git` in your `.dockerignore`.

You don't necessarily need these ignore files.  From where you're starting, I would say these aren't really where your focus should be right now.

I'd take a look at some docker tutorials, maybe this one https://github.com/docker/getting-started